# FindControl problem

Tags: c#, findcontrol

I have a problem regarding with FindControl.I'm using ASPxRoundPanel(with DXperience component) in a repeater. I have a textbox called "txtAdet ID" in ASPxRoundPanel. I just can't access inside the Textbox.And I got the following the error.

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

ascx. code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="urunLinq"
    onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>

    <dxrp:ASPxRoundPanel ID="ASPxRoundPanel1" runat="server" Width="980px" ShowHeader="true" Height="550px">
   <PanelCollection>
   <dxrp:PanelContent>
   <div style="width:980; overflow:hidden;height:350px;">
   <div style="float:left; width:410px;height:310px;">
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="400" Height="300" ImageUrl='<%# "../urunResim/"+Eval("urunAnaResim") %>' runat="server" />
</div>
<div style="float:left;margin-top:0px;overflow:hidden;width:500px;">
<h2><%# Eval("urunAdi") %></h2>

<h4>Ürün Özellikleri</h4>
<p style="font-size:x-small;"><%# Eval("urunOzellikleri") %></p>
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td><h5>Adet    </h5></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAdet" Width="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><h4>        Peşin Fiyatı :</h4></td><td><h3 style="color:Red;">  <%# Eval("kdvliFiyat") %>TL</h3></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">İnternet satış taksitlerini görmek için tıklayın.</a></td>
<td>                
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CommandName="sepeteKaydet" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/icons/sepeteEkle.JPG" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></div>

   </dxrp:PanelContent>
   </PanelCollection>
   <HeaderTemplate>
   <h3><%# Eval("urunAdi") %></h3>
   </HeaderTemplate>
    </dxrp:ASPxRoundPanel>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

.cs  code:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName=="sepeteKaydet")
            {
               TextBox bulunanTextKontrol = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAdet"));
               string urunAdet = bulunanTextKontrol.Text;
               string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
               int urunId=Convert.ToInt32(Request["id"].ToString());
               tempSepet geciciSepet = new tempSepet()
               {
                    adet = Convert.ToInt32(urunAdet),
                    eklemeSaati = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString()),
                    eklemeTarihi = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()),
                    sessionId = sessionId,
                    urunId = urunId
               };
               selcukData.tempSepets.InsertOnSubmit(geciciSepet);
               selcukData.SubmitChanges();
               Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Ürün sepetinize başarıyla eklendi')</script>");
               ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtAdet")).Text = null;
            }
        }
```

I got a error the following line.

```
 string urunAdet = bulunanTextKontrol.Text;
```

Comment: I think, it is bad idea to post here such *big-piece-of-bad-formatted-code* with asking to find a problem. Will be great, if you tried to think over it and ask here some common questions with your suggestions. *(my oppinion)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPxRoundPanel control is a subclass of [ASPxWebControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxClassesASPxWebControltopic) which implements INamingContainer interface. It means that FindControl called on any parent control (RepeaterItem at your case) won't be able to find anything inside ASPxRoundPanel (explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)). So you need at least two steps to accomplish your task:

```
ASPxRoundPanel1 roundPanel =  ((ASPxRoundPanel1)e.Item.FindControl("ASPxRoundPanel1"));
TextBox bulunanTextKontrol = ((TextBox)roundPanel.FindControl("txtAdet"));
```